# What's the final version of Scala3's enum syntax?

Tags: scala, enums, scala-3

I want to override method in enum class, something as the following example mentioned in [Add enum construct](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/1970)

```
enum class Option[+T] extends Serializable {
  def isDefined: Boolean
}
object Option {
  def apply[T](x: T) = if (x != null) Some(x) else None
  case Some[+T](x: T) {
     def isDefined = true
  }
  case None {
     def isDefined = false
  }
}
```

However, the codes does not compiles in Scala 3.0.
How to change the code to make it work? Thanks.

**EDIT** Thanks for @Mario Galic's answer.

I want to grouped a series of compression method as an enum, as following:

```
enum CompressionMethod:
  def compress(out: OutputStream): OutputStream
  def decompress(in: InputStream): InputStream

  case GZIP extends CompressionMethod: ...
  case BZIP extends CompressionMethod: ...
  case NONE extends CompressionMethod: ...
```

It seems ugly if I packed all implementation as:

```
enum CompressionMethod:   
  def compress(out: OutputStream): OutputStream = this match
    case NONE  => out
    case BZIP  => a lot codes ..
    case GZIP  => a lot codes ..
    case ...
```

Moreover, I need to modify the `compress` method if I add another case later other than just add an other `case instance` itself. Something like:

```
enum CompressionMethod:
  def compress(out: OutputStream): OutputStream
  
  case GZIP extends CompressionMethod:
    override def compress(out: OutputStream): OutputStream =
      ...

  case BZIP extends CompressionMethod:
    override def compress(out: OutputStream): OutputStream =
      ...
```

Comment: Have you consulted the [documentation](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/enums/adts.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One tip is to check tests for most up-to-date usage, for example, [tests/run/enum-Option1.scala](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/f1252d8f83ace1561c8f53e132ef94c75be9d287/tests/run/enum-Option1.scala)

```
$ scala3-repl
scala> enum Option1[+T]:
     |   case Some1(x: T)
     |   case None1
     |
     |   def isDefined: Boolean = this match
     |     case None1 => false
     |     case _    => true
     |
// defined class Option1

scala> import Option1.*

scala> Some1(42).isDefined
val res0: Boolean = true

scala> None1.isDefined
val res1: Boolean = false
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I have found this. But the in my case the override method is a lot complicated. It is very ugly to merged all codes in one method.